# How to install a windows service programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have 3 projects in my VS solution. One of them is a Web app, the second one is a Windows Service and the last one a Setup project for my Web app.

What I want is by the end of the installation of the web app in my setup project, within my custom action to try and install my windows service given that I have the location of the assembly by then.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Ok, here is what REALLY worked for me, it has been tested on multiple machines with different OS ( Vista, XP, Win2k, Win2003 server )

The code has been taken from [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/2006-08/msg00238.html) so full credit goes to whoever wrote this piece of code.

Once you add the dll or source file into your project make sure to add the ServiceTools namespace and then you have access to some very handy functionality such as...

```
//Installs and starts the service
ServiceInstaller.InstallAndStart("MyServiceName", "MyServiceDisplayName", "C:\\PathToServiceFile.exe");

//Removes the service
ServiceInstaller.Uninstall("MyServiceName");

//Checks the status of the service
ServiceInstaller.GetServiceStatus("MyServiceName");

//Starts the service
ServiceInstaller.StartService("MyServiceName");

//Stops the service
ServiceInstaller.StopService("MyServiceName");

//Check if service is installed
ServiceInstaller.ServiceIsInstalled("MyServiceName");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've posted an answer that contains some bugfixes to the code you posted. Have a look at the discussion thread that you found the code in, and you'll see that the author of the code realizes that there are some bugs in it.

Comment: The post that I refer to is: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/2006-08/msg00253.html

Also, I found another bug or two where the service handle was not released.

Comment: That solution looks like battling a 25 headed hydra when all you want is a quiet walk in the park ...  there's gotta be a simpler way

Comment: How can I set a certain user and pw under which the service should run? Can I use the ServiceInstaller mentioned above as well?

Comment: if install time longger then 10 seconds, it will report failure.

Answer (score 96):

I found several errors in the code that you reused and have fixed these and also cleaned it up a little. Again, the original code is taken from [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/2006-08/msg00238.html).

```
public static class ServiceInstaller
{
    private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
    private const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class SERVICE_STATUS
    {
        public int dwServiceType = 0;
        public ServiceState dwCurrentState = 0;
        public int dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        public int dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
        public int dwCheckPoint = 0;
        public int dwWaitHint = 0;
    }

    #region OpenSCManager
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, ScmAccessRights dwDesiredAccess);
    #endregion

    #region OpenService
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess);
    #endregion

    #region CreateService
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl, string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);
    #endregion

    #region CloseServiceHandle
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);
    #endregion

    #region QueryServiceStatus
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern int QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
    #endregion

    #region DeleteService
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool DeleteService(IntPtr hService);
    #endregion

    #region ControlService
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern int ControlService(IntPtr hService, ServiceControl dwControl, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
    #endregion

    #region StartService
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int StartService(IntPtr hService, int dwNumServiceArgs, int lpServiceArgVectors);
    #endregion

    public static void Uninstall(string serviceName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);
            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ApplicationException("Service not installed.");

            try
            {
                StopService(service);
                if (!DeleteService(service))
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not delete service " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(service);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        }
    }

    public static bool ServiceIsInstalled(string serviceName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus);

            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                return false;

            CloseServiceHandle(service);
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        }
    }

    public static void InstallAndStart(string serviceName, string displayName, string fileName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);

            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                service = CreateService(scm, serviceName, displayName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart, ServiceError.Normal, fileName, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null);

            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install service.");

            try
            {
                StartService(service);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(service);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        }
    }

    public static void StartService(string serviceName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus | ServiceAccessRights.Start);
            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");

            try
            {
                StartService(service);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(service);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        }
    }

    public static void StopService(string serviceName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus | ServiceAccessRights.Stop);
            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");

            try
            {
                StopService(service);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(service);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        }
    }

    private static void StartService(IntPtr service)
    {
        SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
        StartService(service, 0, 0);
        var changedStatus = WaitForServiceStatus(service, ServiceState.StartPending, ServiceState.Running);
        if (!changedStatus)
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to start service");
    }

    private static void StopService(IntPtr service)
    {
        SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
        ControlService(service, ServiceControl.Stop, status);
        var changedStatus = WaitForServiceStatus(service, ServiceState.StopPending, ServiceState.Stopped);
        if (!changedStatus)
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to stop service");
    }

    public static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(string serviceName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus);
            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                return ServiceState.NotFound;

            try
            {
                return GetServiceStatus(service);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(service);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(scm);
        }
    }

    private static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(IntPtr service)
    {
        SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

        if (QueryServiceStatus(service, status) == 0)
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to query service status.");

        return status.dwCurrentState;
    }

    private static bool WaitForServiceStatus(IntPtr service, ServiceState waitStatus, ServiceState desiredStatus)
    {
        SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

        QueryServiceStatus(service, status);
        if (status.dwCurrentState == desiredStatus) return true;

        int dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int dwOldCheckPoint = status.dwCheckPoint;

        while (status.dwCurrentState == waitStatus)
        {
            // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is
            // one tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no
            // more than 10 seconds.

            int dwWaitTime = status.dwWaitHint / 10;

            if (dwWaitTime < 1000) dwWaitTime = 1000;
            else if (dwWaitTime > 10000) dwWaitTime = 10000;

            Thread.Sleep(dwWaitTime);

            // Check the status again.

            if (QueryServiceStatus(service, status) == 0) break;

            if (status.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
            {
                // The service is making progress.
                dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
                dwOldCheckPoint = status.dwCheckPoint;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Environment.TickCount - dwStartTickCount > status.dwWaitHint)
                {
                    // No progress made within the wait hint
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return (status.dwCurrentState == desiredStatus);
    }

    private static IntPtr OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights rights)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(null, null, rights);
        if (scm == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to service control manager.");

        return scm;
    }
}


public enum ServiceState
{
    Unknown = -1, // The state cannot be (has not been) retrieved.
    NotFound = 0, // The service is not known on the host server.
    Stopped = 1,
    StartPending = 2,
    StopPending = 3,
    Running = 4,
    ContinuePending = 5,
    PausePending = 6,
    Paused = 7
}

[Flags]
public enum ScmAccessRights
{
    Connect = 0x0001,
    CreateService = 0x0002,
    EnumerateService = 0x0004,
    Lock = 0x0008,
    QueryLockStatus = 0x0010,
    ModifyBootConfig = 0x0020,
    StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
    AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | Connect | CreateService |
                 EnumerateService | Lock | QueryLockStatus | ModifyBootConfig)
}

[Flags]
public enum ServiceAccessRights
{
    QueryConfig = 0x1,
    ChangeConfig = 0x2,
    QueryStatus = 0x4,
    EnumerateDependants = 0x8,
    Start = 0x10,
    Stop = 0x20,
    PauseContinue = 0x40,
    Interrogate = 0x80,
    UserDefinedControl = 0x100,
    Delete = 0x00010000,
    StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
    AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | QueryConfig | ChangeConfig |
                 QueryStatus | EnumerateDependants | Start | Stop | PauseContinue |
                 Interrogate | UserDefinedControl)
}

public enum ServiceBootFlag
{
    Start = 0x00000000,
    SystemStart = 0x00000001,
    AutoStart = 0x00000002,
    DemandStart = 0x00000003,
    Disabled = 0x00000004
}

public enum ServiceControl
{
    Stop = 0x00000001,
    Pause = 0x00000002,
    Continue = 0x00000003,
    Interrogate = 0x00000004,
    Shutdown = 0x00000005,
    ParamChange = 0x00000006,
    NetBindAdd = 0x00000007,
    NetBindRemove = 0x00000008,
    NetBindEnable = 0x00000009,
    NetBindDisable = 0x0000000A
}

public enum ServiceError
{
    Ignore = 0x00000000,
    Normal = 0x00000001,
    Severe = 0x00000002,
    Critical = 0x00000003
}
```

Please let me know if anyone finds anything wrong with this code!

Comment: I'm trying to use this code. But I have a problem. The code inside my service is dependent on (needs) the name of the service. And although I use this method `InstallService` with a particular service name, if I'm querying the `ServiceName` property of `ServiceBase` inside my service, it always returns me something else. Any suggestions on how to actually get that name from inside the service?

Comment: how would you use this in conjuncion with the ServiceInstaller and ServiceProcessInstaller?

Comment: Thanks a lot Lars!  This code seems to do exactly what I'm needing it to do, but I've had to change some things because it was being impatient.  the "WaitForServiceStatus" function was breaking and I was getting an "Unable to start service" error, even though the service was actually starting.  I got rid of a lot of checks, and now I have a potential infinite loop, but it works... maybe you have an idea why the function isn't waiting?

Comment: From what I remember, it is highly unpredictable how fast the status for a service changes (same thing applies for uninstallation). I think the documentation mentions this as well.

Comment: Why would you use all this code? Just use AssemblyInstaller.Install()! See @lakshmanaraj's answer.

Comment: I added a simple 3 second Thread.Sleep to the WaitForServiceStatus method when the desiredStatus was equal to Running prior to the first QueryServiceStatus call. 
I found that this allowed a little time to elapse prior to the query for the service to advance from Stopped to StartPending as it would rarely return a solid result for me. This seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Everytime I InstallandStart the service, Error OCCURS "Unable to start service".Can you tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Excellent contribution from Konstantinos but Lars A. Brekken provided the best (bug free) answer.

Comment: Under which license is that code? Can I use it a MS-PL project?

Comment: Seems to work on Windows 7 but on Windows 8.1 `OpenSCManager(...)` == `IntPtr.Zero`. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up using ManagedInstallerClass. See @Newtopian's answer.

Comment: I can get the status of the service (not installed) but cant install the service. it says "Could not connect to service control manager". Can someone help me at this error?

Answer (score 33):

Please have a look at [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sachin.nigam/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically11262005061332AM/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically.aspx).

---

Sometimes you may want to install a Windows Service programmatically, but the target machine does not have InstallUtil.exe.

Add a reference to `System.Configuration.Install`

Use the code below.

Note that the `exeFileName` is the InstallerClass .exe and not the ServiceClass .exe.

```
public static void InstallService(string exeFilename)
{
    string[] commandLineOptions = new string[1] { "/LogFile=install.log" };

    System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer = new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(exeFilename, commandLineOptions);

    installer.UseNewContext = true;    
    installer.Install(null);    
    installer.Commit(null);

}
```

To uninstall:

```
public static void UninstallService(string exeFilename)
{
    string[] commandLineOptions = new string[1] { "/LogFile=uninstall.log" };

    System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer = new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(exeFilename, commandLineOptions);

    installer.UseNewContext = true;    
    installer.Uninstall(null);

}
```

Comment: i have tried that already but it doesn't work. No exceptions or whatever, it just doesn't install the service

Comment: May be full path or credentials problem> U can try writing a simple service.
Have you also tried using the above url where SCM calling appropriate APIs using P/Invoke in C#

Comment: the api/pinvoke way did the job. Apparently the easy way requires an installer to be included in the windows service project.. or so i think.

Comment: my compiler complains that AssemblyInstaller(ExeFilename) consumes more than one argument - it actually seems to have 3 overloads - one has no args, the other two have 2 args each.  has something been changed since you guys posted this?

Comment: i am un-accepting this answer since it didn't worked for me and for others. I will provide my own answer shortly.

Comment: This is the proper way to install an assembly as a service. If it's not working for you then you did something wrong! You don't need all that other 3rd part code. Thanks lakshmanaraj!

Comment: The installation part works for me, but not the uninstall...whether I give a null or empty Hashtable, it tells me that the "savedState" IDictionary doesn't contain the right info...

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. It is simple and it works. (I've suggested an edit since the second parameter is missing. Also, you should reference the InstallerClass and not the ServiceClass as the exeFileName).

Comment: You can see an MSDN example here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(v=vs.110).aspx). (don't need to use `mySavedState`).

Comment: I'm curious: Does it allow you to configure the service name and boot type (automatic, manual, etc)? If yes, how?

Comment: This works, sort of. I get prompted for credentials, then I get  "access denied" on the Installer.Install(null). Anyone have a way around that?

Comment: @FAA Ensure the account is a local admin where you are installing the service. You can try an Impersonation class, like is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: 2022 and still works .net framework 4.8

Answer (score 12):

After creating an instance of an installer class for my service (very basic) all I had to do is to call :

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

to install it and

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

to uninstall the service.  The calling code is, here, in the same assembly as the service executable.

to get the service to install through command line all I had to do is to connect this to the executable though command line arguments  and test for `System.Environment.UserInteractive` to know if it is the service executing or someone trying to install-uninstall it and voila... no funky interop stuff... no pointers leaking...

Total about 20 lines of code spread over two classes did the trick.

to replace InstallUtil just take a look at [ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass.installhelper.aspx)

Comment: Simple. You could have come to the same conclusion when reflecting into InstallUtil.exe. It does exactly the same thing. Plus it's got some interesting console encoding fixups. Install and uninstall works fine. (Remember to run it as Administrator...)

Answer (score 6):

By using the [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) project you can install by calling your executable:

```
MyService.exe install
```

Topshelf also takes care of other Windows Service plumbing.

Answer (score 5):

Since I was faced with the challenge to install services programmatically which run under a certain user. I extended the `InstallAndStart` method to make use of `lp` and `lpPassword`...

Not much but might help.

```
public static void InstallAndStart(
    string serviceName, 
    string displayName, 
    string fileName, 
    string username, 
    string password)
{
    IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

    try
    {
        IntPtr service = OpenService(
            scm, 
            serviceName, 
            ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);

        if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
            service = CreateService(
                scm, 
                serviceName, 
                displayName, 
                ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess, 
                SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, 
                ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart, 
                ServiceError.Normal, 
                fileName, 
                null, 
                IntPtr.Zero, 
                null, 
                username, 
                password);

        if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install service.");

        try
        {
            StartService(service);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(service);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(scm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used Lars answer to manage my service and it works fine. But I needed to pass arguments to service and it took me a couple of hours to find out how to do it. So I decided to post altered class with ability to start service with parameters:

```
    public static class ServiceHelper
    {
        private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
        private const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class SERVICE_STATUS
        {
            public int dwServiceType = 0;
            public ServiceState dwCurrentState = 0;
            public int dwControlsAccepted = 0;
            public int dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
            public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
            public int dwCheckPoint = 0;
            public int dwWaitHint = 0;
        }

        #region OpenSCManager
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, ScmAccessRights dwDesiredAccess);
        #endregion

        #region OpenService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess);
        #endregion

        #region CreateService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl, string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);
        #endregion

        #region CloseServiceHandle
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);
        #endregion

        #region QueryServiceStatus
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
        #endregion

        #region DeleteService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool DeleteService(IntPtr hService);
        #endregion

        #region ControlService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int ControlService(IntPtr hService, ServiceControl dwControl, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
        #endregion

        #region StartService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int StartService(IntPtr hService, int dwNumServiceArgs, string[] lpServiceArgVectors);
        #endregion

        public static void Uninstall(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Service not installed.");

                try
                {
                    StopService(service);
                    if (!DeleteService(service))
                        throw new ApplicationException("Could not delete service " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static bool ServiceIsInstalled(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return false;

                CloseServiceHandle(service);
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static void InstallAndStart(string serviceName, string displayName, string fileName,string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    service = CreateService(scm, serviceName, displayName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart, ServiceError.Normal, fileName, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install service.");

                try
                {
                    StartService(service,args);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static void StartService(string serviceName,string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus | ServiceAccessRights.Start);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");

                try
                {
                    StartService(service,args);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static void StopService(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus | ServiceAccessRights.Stop);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");

                try
                {
                    StopService(service);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        private static void StartService(IntPtr service,string[] args)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            StartService(service, args.Length, args);
            var changedStatus = WaitForServiceStatus(service, ServiceState.StartPending, ServiceState.Running);
            if (!changedStatus)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to start service");
        }

        private static void StopService(IntPtr service)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            ControlService(service, ServiceControl.Stop, status);
            var changedStatus = WaitForServiceStatus(service, ServiceState.StopPending, ServiceState.Stopped);
            if (!changedStatus)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to stop service");
        }

        public static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return ServiceState.NotFound;

                try
                {
                    return GetServiceStatus(service);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        private static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(IntPtr service)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

            if (QueryServiceStatus(service, status) == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to query service status.");

            return status.dwCurrentState;
        }

        private static bool WaitForServiceStatus(IntPtr service, ServiceState waitStatus, ServiceState desiredStatus)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

            QueryServiceStatus(service, status);
            if (status.dwCurrentState == desiredStatus) return true;

            int dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            int dwOldCheckPoint = status.dwCheckPoint;

            while (status.dwCurrentState == waitStatus)
            {
                // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is
                // one tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no
                // more than 10 seconds.

                int dwWaitTime = status.dwWaitHint / 10;

                if (dwWaitTime < 1000) dwWaitTime = 1000;
                else if (dwWaitTime > 10000) dwWaitTime = 10000;

                Thread.Sleep(dwWaitTime);

                // Check the status again.

                if (QueryServiceStatus(service, status) == 0) break;

                if (status.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
                {
                    // The service is making progress.
                    dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
                    dwOldCheckPoint = status.dwCheckPoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Environment.TickCount - dwStartTickCount > status.dwWaitHint)
                    {
                        // No progress made within the wait hint
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (status.dwCurrentState == desiredStatus);
        }

        private static IntPtr OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights rights)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(null, null, rights);
            if (scm == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to service control manager.");

            return scm;
        }
    }


    public enum ServiceState
    {
        Unknown = -1, // The state cannot be (has not been) retrieved.
        NotFound = 0, // The service is not known on the host server.
        Stopped = 1,
        StartPending = 2,
        StopPending = 3,
        Running = 4,
        ContinuePending = 5,
        PausePending = 6,
        Paused = 7
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ScmAccessRights
    {
        Connect = 0x0001,
        CreateService = 0x0002,
        EnumerateService = 0x0004,
        Lock = 0x0008,
        QueryLockStatus = 0x0010,
        ModifyBootConfig = 0x0020,
        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | Connect | CreateService |
                     EnumerateService | Lock | QueryLockStatus | ModifyBootConfig)
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ServiceAccessRights
    {
        QueryConfig = 0x1,
        ChangeConfig = 0x2,
        QueryStatus = 0x4,
        EnumerateDependants = 0x8,
        Start = 0x10,
        Stop = 0x20,
        PauseContinue = 0x40,
        Interrogate = 0x80,
        UserDefinedControl = 0x100,
        Delete = 0x00010000,
        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | QueryConfig | ChangeConfig |
                     QueryStatus | EnumerateDependants | Start | Stop | PauseContinue |
                     Interrogate | UserDefinedControl)
    }

    public enum ServiceBootFlag
    {
        Start = 0x00000000,
        SystemStart = 0x00000001,
        AutoStart = 0x00000002,
        DemandStart = 0x00000003,
        Disabled = 0x00000004
    }

    public enum ServiceControl
    {
        Stop = 0x00000001,
        Pause = 0x00000002,
        Continue = 0x00000003,
        Interrogate = 0x00000004,
        Shutdown = 0x00000005,
        ParamChange = 0x00000006,
        NetBindAdd = 0x00000007,
        NetBindRemove = 0x00000008,
        NetBindEnable = 0x00000009,
        NetBindDisable = 0x0000000A
    }

    public enum ServiceError
    {
        Ignore = 0x00000000,
        Normal = 0x00000001,
        Severe = 0x00000002,
        Critical = 0x00000003
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this article I read all posts and comments Bu still I don't know How can I set Account Type and StartType method when I gonna add windows service. This code example works fine my side its just add a service own local system) But I prepare Setup program I must think **StartMode** and **User Account Type** method because of customers system.
  there is every appearance that **ServiceBootFlag** enum provide StartType but **Account Type** still a problem.

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateServiceA")]

    private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string

    lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceRights dwDesiredAccess, int

    dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl,

    string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string

    lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to install windows service using C#:

```
public void InstallWinService(string winServicePath)
{
        try
        {
            ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { winServicePath});
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be using SC.exe from command prompt:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 startInfo.Arguments = "/C sc create MyService binpath=\"c:\\...\\MyService.exe\"";
 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();
```