# Installing a .NET Windows Service on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services, installation

I have created a Windows Service (called MuskOx) which runs on my development machine (which obviously has Visual Studio installed).

The Bin folder of the project contains the following files:

- InstallUtil.InstallLog
- muskox.InstallLog
- muskox.InstallState
- MuskOx.exe.config
- MuskOx.vshost.exe
- MuskOx.vshost.exe.config
- MuskOx.vshost.exe.manifest
- Kctc.dll (a class library used by MuskOx)
- Kctc.pdb
- MuskOx.exe
- MuskOx.pdb

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to install the service on another machine which doesn't have VS installed? I haven't the faintest idea what half of those files do and I'm finding Googling answers a little unproductive.

Thanks

David

Comment: +1 for MuskOx as the name of your service.

Comment: refer to the link is you would prefer for your service to install/uninstall itself (instead of requiring the use of InstallUtil.exe).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy MuskOx.exe and Kctc.dll to the target machine.  Run installutil.exe to get it registered, its available in c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727

Comment: Cool, I think that's what I need to know. I'll let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ship any of the .vshost.* files.  The pdb files are debug files so only ship those if you want symbols in your debug output.  And of course when installing the service on another machine, InstallLog and InstallState files should get generated so you don't need to ship those either.

Comment: Thanks for the details of the files, but how do I actually physically install the service?

Answer (score 0):

For .net applications use the [installutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx) as Hans already pointed out. You can also use [sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) to install and uninstall services.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with your application:

[How to install a windows service programmatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358700/how-to-install-a-windows-service-programmatically-in-c)