# How do I determine if services.msc snap-in is loaded into mmc console?

Tags: c++, windows, wix, windows-installer, mmc

I need to prompt user to close services.msc snap-in on program uninstall. How do I do that?

Comment: What is your goal with this?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321825/verify-if-a-service-is-marked-for-deletion

Comment: Sometimes my service cannot be registered because of services applet running.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. I don't have a ready answer. There are two possible, non-exclusive approaches: 1) Help the uninstaller user understand that uninstallation should not proceed/won't be fully complete until all processes release handles to the service, or 2) Help the installer user understand that installation cannot proceed/will fail unless all processes release handles to the service scheduled for deletion. Detecting (1) might be harder, but could be narrowed to just detecting the services snap-in, as you suggest. Detecting (2) would still require a custom action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom action to do that. You can use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx) to check whether services.msc is loaded in mmc or not.

```
  [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        foreach (Process getProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (getProcess.ProcessName.Contains("mmc"))
            {
                if (getProcess.MainWindowTitle == "Services")
                {
                    session["SERVICES_MSC"] = "Running";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

Calls the Custom action in uninstall and stop the uninstallation based on the **SERVICES_MSC** property.

```
<Binary Id="Check_Services" SourceFile="..\TestProject\bin\Release\TestProject.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CHECK_SERVICES" BinaryKey="Check_Services" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Return="check" />

<CustomAction Id="STOP_INSTALLATION" Error="Services.msc is running.Please close that Window before uninstall the setup." />
```

Inside the Install Execute sequence call the custom actions.

```
  <Custom Action="CHECK_SERVICES" After="InstallValidate">REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Custom>
  <Custom Action="STOP_INSTALLATION" After="CHECK_SERVICES">(REMOVE ~= "ALL") AND SERVICES_MSC</Custom>
```

Comment: Thank you. But if you first run mmc and then load services applet by File->Add/Remove Snap-In and leave focus on Console Root then window title will not contain "Services". Also the name of the applet might be localized to a different language.