# Programmatically remove a service using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a windows service programmatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358700/how-to-install-a-windows-service-programmatically-in-c)

Is there a way to programmatically remove a service using C# without having to execute "InstallUtil.exe /u MyService.exe"?

Comment: Is this a service written in C#?

Comment: Note: None of the methods listed below will work from a web page running in IIS. IIS won't allow it due to security concerns.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceInstaller.Uninstall method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.uninstall.aspx) in System.ServiceProcess.dll.  For example:

```
ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller(); 
InstallContext Context = new InstallContext("<<log file path>>", null); 
ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context; 
ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = "MyService"; 
ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);
```

This method will attempt to stop the service first before uninstalling.

Comment: I don't understand, the Uninstall method takes the savedState, not the name of the service.

Comment: You're right.  Updated with another example I found..

Comment: InstallContext not in System.ServicesProcess

Comment: For those still looking for it, InstallContext is in System.Configuration.Install

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass
                            .InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", executablePath });
```

Comment: For any reason it claims the service is not installed, but it is. It's an external service written in .NET. I got admin rights on my process.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is to uninstall a service, you've written, from within itself and you've added an installer to the project, you can simply instantiate your Installer class and call Uninstall.  For example, if you dragged an installer onto the designer service and named that component "ProjectInstaller", you can get your service to uninstall itself with the following code:

```
var installer = new ProjectInstaller();
installer.Uninstall(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are listed in the Windows Registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services. If you remove the key corresponding to the service's given name (not the display name; the one under which it was registered), you will have effectively "unregistered" the service. You can do this programmatically with the [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) object. You will need CAS permissions on the executing computer to modify registry entries.

Comment: +1 This may not be recommended, it has the benefit of actually working. :)  An alternative  is to `CreateProcess sc.exe delete ServiceName`.