# How to install a window service programmatically in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

How can I install my Windows service programmatically?

I want to install my Windows service on clicking of a register button & uninstall it on clicking a de-register button.

Comment: Just use the Process class to run InstallUtil.exe.  This is in general a fairly bad idea since this requires admin privileges and UAC elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Reference (in **C#** however):

[How to install a windows service programmatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358700/how-to-install-a-windows-service-programmatically-in-c)

```
//Installs and starts the service
ServiceInstaller.InstallAndStart("MyServiceName", "MyServiceDisplayName", "C:\PathToServiceFile.exe");

//Removes the service
ServiceInstaller.Uninstall("MyServiceName");

//Checks the status of the service
ServiceInstaller.GetServiceStatus("MyServiceName");

//Starts the service
ServiceInstaller.StartService("MyServiceName");

//Stops the service
ServiceInstaller.StopService("MyServiceName");

//Check if service is installed
ServiceInstaller.ServiceIsInstalled("MyServiceName");
```