# how can I set Account Type and StartType method when add a window service automatically?

Tags: c#, windows-services

The code has been taken from [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/152585/ServiceInstaller.cs) This code example works fine my side its just add a service own local system) But I prepare Setup program I must think **StartMode** and **User Account Type** method because of customers system.
  so How can I set **Account Type** and **StartType** method when I gonna add windows service.
  there is every appearance that **ServiceBootFlag** enum provide StartType but **Account Type** still a problem. Or I'm open different idiom for set mentioned method for adding a windows service programmatically
  And I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358700/how-to-install-a-windows-service-programmatically-in-c) all post and comments I didn't see anything for set Startmode and User Account Type method When add a windows service.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateServiceA")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string
    lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceRights dwDesiredAccess, int
    dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl,
    string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string
    lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);
```