# how to install windows service (Kerio vpn client service) correctly?

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service

I'm try to install service from C# and using **`ServiceTools.dll`** ([Source](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/152585/ServiceInstaller.cs) - [Dll](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/152585/ServiceTools.dll) - [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358700/how-to-install-a-windows-service-programmatically-in-c)) and also using from **`InstallUtil.exe`** but service is not installed or don't start after install !

when i use from `InstallUtil.exe` : (32bit and 64bit / with .net 1-...-4) 
use from this commend :

> InstallUtil "Service File Path"
>
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.303\InstallUtil.exe"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kerio\VPN Client\kvpncsvc.exe"

But i get following  error :

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Prog ram Files (x86)\Kerio\VPN Client\kvpncsvc.exe' or one
>   of its dependencies. The m odule was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest..

and also if install service with `ServiceTools.dll`
use from this commend :

```
ServiceInstaller.InstallAndStart("Service Name", "Service Display Name", "Service File Path");
ServiceInstaller.InstallAndStart("KrSVC", "Krio service", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kerio\VPN Client\kvpncsvc.exe");
```

It's work and service installed but Service don't start and  i get following  error :

```
Windows could not start the KrSVC service on a local computer
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

**Note :**

- when i install kerio vpn client sevice correctly installed and
  worked and also can start /stop/etc...
- For install service first of all i remove kerio vpn client or unistall kvpncsvc service
- kvpncsvc have a service however can start with user interface
  and if double click on it it's open like desktop app.
- and also i was checked InstallUtil 32 bit and 64 bit from .net 2 or etc..
- kerio vpn client is her : [32bit](http://cdn.kerio.com/dwn/control/control-8.3.1-2108/kerio-control-vpnclient-8.3.1-2108-win32.exe) - [64bit](http://cdn.kerio.com/dwn/control/control-8.3.1-2108/kerio-control-vpnclient-8.3.1-2108-win64.exe) - [site](http://www.kerio.com/support/kerio-control)

Now i want to know how can i install or start this service ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Resolution:
1. Enable Keiro Virtual  Network Adapter (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections)
2. Start Keiro VPN CLient Service
3. Run Keiro VPN Client

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have admin rights on the system. Start Command window as administrator.
Make sure all the dependencies are in same folder.