# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to unninstall a service c#

Tags: c#, object, reference

I have the following code that stops and un-installs a service.
It stops the service correctly but it gives me this error when I try to un-install:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
   at UpdateOrca.FuncoesUpdater.StopService(String serviceName, Int32 timeoutMilliseconds, Boolean Unninstall) in C:\Users\me\Downloads\UpdateOrcaV2013\UpdateOrca\UpdateOrca\FuncoesUpdater.cs:line 165
```

Code:

```
    public void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds, bool Unninstall)
    {
        if (ServicoInstalado(serviceName) == true) //&& ServiceRunning(serviceName) == true
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
                ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
                if (Unninstall == true)
                {
                    ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = serviceName;
                    ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null); (LINE OF THE ERROR)
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.Erro = ex.ToString();
                Erro NewErro = new Erro();
                NewErro.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ServiceInstaller.Uninstall()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.uninstall(v=vs.110).aspx) method actually requires some type of context information about what you are uninstalling. This can generally be passed in as an `IDictionary` object to the `Uninstall()` method, but if you decide to pass `null` in instead, you'll probably need to set the context explicitly :

```
// Build your uninstaller
ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
if (Unninstall)
{
      // Set a context (using a specific file to log uninstall info)
      ServiceInstallerObj.Context = new InstallContext("{path-to-log-file}", null);
      // Continue setting your service and uninstalling it
      ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = serviceName;
      ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null); 
}
```

If that doesn't work, you may consider trying an approach similar to the one mentioned in [this related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/358700/557445).